# SQL Group by string and cut results by symbol

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I use MySql and I have table like this

```
id |city               | address         | work_time
-------------------------------
1  |London - center    |London street 1  |7am - 10 pm
2  |London - center 2  |London street 2  |7am - 10 pm
3  |London - center 3  |London street 3  |7am - 10 pm
4  |Paris - bol 1      |Bol street 3     |9am - 10 pm
5  |Paris - bol 2      |Bol street 13    |9am - 10 pm
```

How to group all cities by first string before `-` and to crop all letters after this symbol? 
I want to show in list only London and Paris like that

```
  id |city               
  -------------------------------
  1  |London 
  2  |Paris
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Where does `id = 2` for Paris come from? The two rows for Paris have IDs = 4 and 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, ' -', 1) AS city
FROM yourtable
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xg9rtiNy5AKnYbX4mdiFMd/0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `locate()` function

```
select distinct substring(city,1,locate(' -',city)) as city
```